# GPUImage increasing video filter speed for iphone 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, gpuimage, iphone-4

I'm using GPUImage to apply filters to videos, and everything works fine on iPhone 4S and up, but on iPhone 4, things get really slow (it takes 30-40 seconds to apply filter to a 6 second video). Audio is disabled while applying filters

```
movieFile.audioEncodingTarget = nil;
_movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio= YES;
```

is there a way for me to increase the performance any further on iphone 4? I tried decreasing the output size but it did not do much. Can I remove the audio code completely from GPUImage to increase performance since I'm adding the audio later on to the movie file?

Sample code:

```
//Initialize the filter
_filter = [[GPUImageContrastFilter alloc] init];
[(GPUImageContrastFilter *)_filter setContrast:1.75];

finalMoviePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%s", NSTemporaryDirectory(), filteredVideoFileName];
_finalMovieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalMoviePath];

//Delete Previous Filtered Video File
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:finalMoviePath]) {
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:finalMoviePath error:&error]) {
    }
}

//Create the GPUImageMovie
movieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:video.URL];
movieFile.runBenchmark = NO;

[movieFile addTarget:_filter];

//MovieWriter
_movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:_finalMovieURL size:movieSize];
movieFile.audioEncodingTarget = nil;
_movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio= YES;

movieFile.playAtActualSpeed = NO;
[movieFile startProcessing];
[_filter addTarget:_movieWriter];

[_movieWriter startRecording];


[_movieWriter setCompletionBlock:^{  
    //Completion stuff
}];
```

Comment: what is your deployment target and what is device IOS version for iPhone 4?

Comment: My deployment target is 6.0 and the device is 6.1.3

Comment: Quite frankly, the iPhone 4 isn't the fastest device out there. Encoding MP4 video does tax the device, even with the hardware acceleration present in the iPhone. As far as the audio code goes, it isn't enabled at all if you set a nil audioEncodingTarget, so removing any code in the encoder regarding it won't do you any good (and could make maintenance a lot more difficult). Under the hood, one optimization that could be made would be to split the BGRA output texture back into YUV planar form for passing into the movie encoder, but that would take a little work to pull off.

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep working on it